# How to Sort if Index shows blank value in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing

Im looking for a way to SORT the results of INDEX if there is a blank cell it should put the blank either first or last.

```
=IFERROR(SORT(INDEX(EQUIPMENT!$D$10:$D$900,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$134:A134,EQUIPMENT!$D$10:$D$900),0))),"")
```

The above code gives the result as the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Bit confused. If you have access to the `SORT` function then you also have access to `FILTER` and `UNIQUE`, so simply `=LET(ζ,EQUIPMENT!$D$10:$D$900,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(ζ,ζ<>""))))`, which also has the benefit of spilling all results.

Comment: This Works !!! So you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

`=LET(ζ,EQUIPMENT!$D$10:$D$900,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(ζ,ζ<>""))))`